# How to access the next page using JIRA -REST-API for python

Tags: python, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I am trying to fetch all issues related to a project. When I execute the below code, I get only 50 results. I need to navigate all pages and get all the bugs.Please help

```
all_issues = jira.search_issues('project=ProjectName')
    each_issue = sorted([issue.key for issue in all_issues])
    for item in each_issue:
        print item
```

This gives me only 50 issues since the page has default value of 50. I need to get all the issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**-- Update 18/Oct/2021**

As discovered in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608446/748560), setting maxResults to False appears to remove the limit on the result set.

```
all_issues = jira.search_issues('project=ProjectName', maxResults=False)
```

**-- Original Post**

Try;

```
all_issues = jira.search_issues('project=ProjectName', maxResults=50, startAt=50)
```

The results from the REST API are paged, with the default number of results being 50. You can supply the `startAt` value to start the results from a point in the result set. By default this value is 0.

So, your original query would get results 0-49, the query above would get results 50-99 and changing `startAt` to 100 would get 100-149, and so on.

You can also increase the value of `maxResults` to return more results per page. However, this is limited to the max value of `jira.search.views.default.max` configured in your JIRA instance (set to 1000 by default).

It is not possible to make the API return all issues without paging. You would have to configure `jira.search.views.default.max` to a very large value and supply that value as `maxResults`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works awesome. As you said it limits the value to 1000. I tried setting the value for 'jira.search.views.default.max'. But I get an error 'AttributeError: 'JIRA' object has no attribute 'search''. I want to fetch about 10000 issues. Is there a way?

Comment: Where are you setting jira.search.views.default.max? This is a JIRA global configuration, it needs to be set in jira-config.properties for the JIRA installation.

Comment: @rakesh: is there any way to paginate it easily? Can i predict how many items could be returned in total?

Comment: @Lormitto I guess number of items returned depends on the value that you set for `maxResults`.

Comment: This answer is not correct, since you will always do a new request when you change the startAt. If you e.g. process issues in a way that they won't appear in the search afterwards you will skip some issues

Comment: @AndréDüwel I think stating "it is incorrect" is a bit far; it is a "limitation" that needs to be considered for sure; but with the unfortunate max limit imposed in the search, there isn't another way, unless perhaps you can provide your wisdom?

Comment: @JamieB sorry for not directly posting the solution, I found your answer and used it since I just had to accomplish one small task and during that I realized that "limitation".

Sorry if you felt offended, that wasn't my intention. I just wanted to share my finding. And I assumed that there will be a better way, since the returned object contains a boolean property: `isLast`

After taking the time to look up the source code I found the solution an posted as here as an alternative answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69608446/4248497 . Hoping it will help other people in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the source code:
https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/f5d7dd032e719fe35f5fc377f302200f6c69afd4/jira/client.py#L2737

Setting `maxResults=False` should do the trick, so your example would look like:

```
all_issues = jira.search_issues('project=ProjectName', maxResults=False)
    each_issue = sorted([issue.key for issue in all_issues])
    for item in each_issue:
        print item
```

I shortly tested it right now and it worked here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get all issues - or a desired max number - using the pagination capability of the API. This gets as many issues as possible with each call to `search_issues`, stopping when the requested max number is reached or there are no more available issues.

```
def get_issues(jira, query, max=(1<<31)-1):
    issues = []
    start = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        nextpage = jira.search_issues(query, startAt=start, maxResults=(max - start))
        issues.extend(nextpage)
        start = start + len(nextpage)
        done = (start >= max) or (len(nextpage) == 0)
    return issues
```

With this, the OP's issue search becomes:

```
all_issues = get_issues(jira, 'project=ProjectName')
```

But if you only want the first 100 issues, use this instead:

```
all_issues = get_issues(jira, 'project=ProjectName', max=100)
```

This is more efficient than calling `search_issues` with `maxResults=False`, which internally paginates through *all* issues.

The default value of `max` is 2^31 - 1, the largest positive signed 32-bit integer, which is the highest value supported by the JIRA API.